# How to get output without brackets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sage

I wrote the following code in SageMath to generate a random system of polynomial equations.

```
def quad_polynomial(field, n, m):
    Polynomial_Ring1 = PolynomialRing(K, ['x%s'%p for p in range(1, n + 1)])
    x1 = Polynomial_Ring1.gens()
    gen_Polynomial_Ring1 = matrix(x1)
    list_of_quadratic_part = [0 for i in range(m)]
    for i in range(m):
        list_of_quadratic_part[i] = gen_Polynomial_Ring1 * (random_matrix(K, n)) * gen_Polynomial_Ring1.transpose()
        # print(list_of_quadratic_part[i])
    return list_of_quadratic_part

def linear_and_constant_terms(field, n, m):
    a = []
    Polynomial_Ring1 = PolynomialRing(K, ['x%s'%p for p in range(1, n + 1)])
    varlist = (list(Polynomial_Ring1.gens()))
    v = matrix(varlist)
    LandC = [0 for i in range(m)]
    for i in range(m):
        im1 = matrix([K.random_element() for j in range(n)])
        expression = im1 * v.transpose()
        LandC[i] = expression
    return LandC

def final_expression_F(field, n, m):
    final_expression = [0 for i in range(m)]
    for i in range(m):
        final_expression[i] = quad_polynomial(field, n, m)[i] + linear_and_constant_terms(field, n, m)[i]
    return final_expression
```

When I run the code, I am getting polynomial in square brackets which I don't want.

```
sage: P = final_expression_F(K, 2, 3)
sage: print(P)
[[(a)*x1^2 + x1*x2 + (a + 1)*x1],
 [(a)*x1^2 + (a)*x2^2 + x1 + (a + 1)*x2],
 [x1^2 + (a)*x1*x2 + (a)*x2^2 + (a)*x1 + x2]]
```

I want my output to be like this

```
[(a)*x1^2 + x1*x2 + (a + 1)*x1,
 (a)*x1^2 + (a)*x2^2 + x1 + (a + 1)*x2,
 x1^2 + (a)*x1*x2 + (a)*x2^2 + (a)*x1 + x2]
```

Can someone please help? I have spent too much time on this but I am not able to resolve the issue.

Edit: using the answer by @U11-Forward I am getting round brackets.

```
sage: P = final_expression_F(K, 2, 3)
sage: P = [j for i in P for j in i]
sage: print(P)
[((a + 1)*x1*x2 + x2^2 + (a + 1)*x1 + (a + 1)*x2),
 ((a + 1)*x1 + (a)*x2),
 ((a + 1)*x1^2 + (a)*x1*x2 + x2^2 + (a + 1)*x1 + (a)*x2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following does the whole job in a more natural way. It makes no sense to use the parameter `m` all the time, when a simple final list comprehension solves its issue. Below it becomes the anonymous variable `_`. (Your `field` and `K` variables are not really fixed in the OP. I'll go the way i think that things make sense.)

```
def quad_polynomial(K, n):
    R = PolynomialRing(K, [f'x{p}' for p in [1..n]])
    gens_R = matrix(R, 1, n, R.gens())
    return ( gens_R * random_matrix(K, n, n) * gens_R.transpose() +
             gens_R * random_matrix(K, n, 1) +
             random_matrix(K, 1, 1) )[0, 0]

P = [quad_polynomial(QQ, 2) for _ in [1..3]]
```

The above delivers this time:

```
sage: P
[2*x1^2 - x1*x2 - 1/2*x1 + x2 - 1,
 -2*x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + 2*x2^2 - 1/2*x1 + x2 - 1,
 x1*x2 + 2*x2^2 - 2*x1]
sage:
```

The entries of this result are random polynomials of degree two in `n` variables, also including a constant term. (Which comes from the 1x1 random matrix.)

*Note:* In the returned value of the routine `quad_polynomial`, which is of the shape `( ... )[0, 0]`, note that the part `( ... )` is a 1x1 matrix, to extract its one and only entry, we use that `[0, 0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a list of lists. You would need to flatten the lists:

```
print([j for i in P for j in i])
```

Comment: How can I store that value. P=final_expression_F(K,2,3)
P=[j for i in P for j in i]
print(P). If I am doing this it is giving me round brackets. But if I directly print as per your instructions it is working. How can I store the results.

Comment: Can you share the output?

Comment: it seems that python is grouping the output for clarity, i would transform each entry to string before printing `str(P)` and change P to format it the way i want

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your `final_expression_F` function, try changing it:

```
    return final_expression
```

To:

```
    return [i for x in final_expression for i in x]
```

Comment: [(x2^2 + (a + 1)*x1 + x2), ((a + 1)*x1*x2 + (a)*x2^2 + (a + 1)*x1 + x2), (x1^2 + (a + 1)*x1*x2 + (a + 1)*x2^2 + x1 + x2)] Now I am getting round brackets.

Comment: @AB maybe try: `return [i[1:-1] or x in final_expression for i in x]`

Answer (score 0):

Three ways to rewrite the function, starting from @dan_fulea's insightful answer.

We can directly produce a scalar (instead of producing
a 1x1 matrix and extracting its single entry):

```py
def my_random_polynomial_a(K, n):
    r"""
    Return a random polynomial of degree ≤ 2 in variables `x_1`, ... `x_n` over `K`.
    """
    R = PolynomialRing(K, [f'x{p}' for p in [1 .. n]])
    x = vector(R, n, R.gens())
    return (x * random_matrix(K, n, n) * x
            + random_vector(K, n) * x
            + K.random_element())
```

We can avoid matrices and vectors and directly pick the polynomial's
`n(n+1)/2` coefficients as random field elements (the previous approach
picked `n^2 + n + 1` random field elements):

```py
def my_random_polynomial_b(K, n):
    r"""
    Return a random polynomial of degree ≤ 2 in `x_1`, ... `x_n` over `K`.
    """
    R = PolynomialRing(K, [f'x{p}' for p in [1 .. n]])
    xx = (R.one(),) + R.gens()
    r = K.random_element
    return sum((r() * x * y for k, x in enumerate(xx) for y in xx[k:]), R.zero())
```

We can produce the polynomial from a dictionary of (monomial, coefficient) pairs,
using Sage's `IntegerVectors` to enumerate the acceptable monomials:

```py
def my_random_polynomial_c(K, n):
    r"""
    Return a random polynomial of degree ≤ 2 in `x_1`, ... `x_n` over `K`.
    """
    R = PolynomialRing(K, [f'x{p}' for p in [1 .. n]])
    r = K.random_element
    return R({tuple(v): r() for d in range(3) for v in IntegerVectors(d, n)})
```

Example: list of 3 random polynomials of degree ≤ 2 in `x1`, `x2` over ℤ.

Using `my_random_polynomial_a`:

```py
sage: P = [my_random_polynomial_a(ZZ, 2) for _ in range(3)]
sage: P
[3*x1^2 + 6*x1*x2 - x2^2 + x1 - x2,
 -4*x1^2 + 3*x1*x2 + x2^2 - 4*x2 + 1,
 -28*x1^2 + 9*x1*x2 + 2*x1 + x2 - 3]
```

Using `my_random_polynomial_b`:

```py
sage: P = [my_random_polynomial_b(ZZ, 2) for _ in range(3)]
sage: P
[x1^2 + x1*x2 + 11*x2^2 - 2*x1 + x2 + 1,
 2*x1^2 - 3*x1*x2 - x2^2 - x1 - 6*x2 + 1,
 -16*x1*x2 - x2^2 - 2*x2 - 1]
```

Using `my_random_polynomial_c`:

```py
sage: P = [my_random_polynomial_c(ZZ, 2) for _ in range(3)]
sage: P
[-8*x1^2 - x2^2 - 12*x1 + 7*x2 - 6,
 2*x1^2 + x1*x2 - 2*x2^2 + 2*x1 + 120*x2 + 1,
 -2*x1*x2 - x2^2 - 2*x1 + 1]
```